# How to parse specific data from query string in a url in C#?

Tags: asp.net, url

I want to parse the data from a URL query string and store it. Given below is my sample URL. From this I want to parse the data and store somewhere

```
http://www.example.com/default.aspx?VN=919999999999&Rawmessage=urlTest&Time=2013-04-08 12:32:04&Send=919000000002&MID=101878052
```

I want to store VN and Rawmessage into these strings,

```
string x = Request.QueryString["VN"]
string y = Request.QueryString["Rawmessage"]
```

Please help me find a solution.

Comment: Atleast take care of spellings in question

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. Where you are getting issue in getting query string values

Comment: @RahulNikate: I got all these ideas from internet. I don't know, how to apply this in c# coding in a proper order. Can you post a demo code. Please.

Comment: Reshma, internet is telling you the right thing,and you're hitting the right spot!

Well, you copied the sample from some demo alright!

Comment: @Sunny : My page is running with another url. I want to fetch data from the above given url while my page loading.

Comment: If I'm not getting wrong you need to parse the Query String Key-Value Pair and use the values somewhere else. If that is the case then you should frame your questions carefully!

Check for my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in the `Page_Load()` function in `Default.aspx.cs` file.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string x = Request.QueryString["VN"];
        string y = Request.QueryString["Rawmessage"];
    }
```

Comment: Hi kumar. My page is running with another url. I want to fetch data from the above given url while my page loading.

Comment: @Reshma: Request.QueryString[] is to get the querystring key value from the current loading page's URL. what you exactly want?

Comment: I want to pass the above url on my page load. From there I have fetch data and store into string.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the discussion we had, I think you want to parse the query string key-value pair and use the values somewhere else.

Also, ASP.Net doesn't have to do anything with parsing, It's a pure C# problem.

I'm giving the sample solution to the problem in the context of a Console App, you're free to reuse the codes as per your taste.

```
var inputUrl =
@"http://www.example.com/default.aspx?VN=919999999999&Rawmessage=urlTest&Time=2013-04-08 12:32:04&Send=919000000002&MID=101878052";

int index = inputUrl.IndexOf("?");

var queryString = inputUrl
                .Substring(index + 1)
                .Split('&');
foreach (var strKeyValuePair in queryString)
  {
     var keyValPair = strKeyValuePair.Split('=');
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: 
                   {1}",keyValPair[0],keyValPair[1]);
  }

Console.WriteLine("\n============================================\n\n");

string VN = queryString.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("VN"));
string RawMessage = queryString.FirstOrDefault(x => 
                            x.StartsWith("Rawmessage"));

Console.WriteLine("VN: {0}",VN.Split('=')[1]);
Console.WriteLine("RawMessage: {0}", RawMessage.Split('=')[1]);

Console.ReadLine(); // just to halt the console
```